# Value Error saying The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am working on a project and i am trying to add products in the cart, but i am facing an issue : ValueError at /onlineshopping/add-to-cart/p1/, this is the location. The logic also checks whether the item is current present in the order or not to not create duplicate items.
I am not getting where am i wrong. Please help me out.

Here is urls.py:

```
path('cart/', views.cart, name='cart'),
path('add-to-cart/<str:slug>/', add_to_cart, name='add-to-cart'),
```

Here is models.py:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(AffProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Here is views.py:

```
@login_required
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = AffProduct.objects.filter(slug=slug)
    order_item = OrderItem.objects.get(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()
            messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated.")
            return redirect("cart")
        else:
            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item was added to your cart.")
            return redirect("cart")
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(
            user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        messages.info(request, "This item was added to your cart.")
        return redirect("cart")
```

This is my cart.html:

```
{% block content %}
  <main>
    <div class="container">

    <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
    <h2>Order Summary</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Item title</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Item Price</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for order_item in object.items.all %}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
            <td>{{ order_item.item.product_title }}</td>
            <td>{{ order_item.item.sale_price }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href=""><i class="fas fa-minus mr-2"></i></a>
                {{ order_item.quantity }}
                <a href="{% url 'core:add-to-cart' order_item.item.slug %}"><i class="fas fa-plus ml-2"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td>
            {% if order_item.item.discount %}
                ${{ order_item.get_total_discount_item_price }}
                <span class="badge badge-primary">Saving ${{ order_item.get_amount_saved }}</span>
            {% else %}
                ${{ order_item.get_total_item_price }}
            {% endif %}
            <a style='color: red;' href="{% url 'core:remove-from-cart' order_item.item.slug %}">
                <i class="fas fa-trash float-right"></i>
            </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% empty %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan='5'>Your cart is empty</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
            <a class='btn btn-primary float-right' href='/'>Continue shopping</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        <!--{% if object.coupon %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><b>Coupon</b></td>
            <td><b>-${{ object.coupon.amount }}</b></td>
        </tr>
        {% endif %}-->
        {% if object.get_total %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><b>Order Total</b></td>
            <td><b>${{ object.get_total }}</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
            <a class='btn btn-warning float-right ml-2' href=''>Proceed to checkout</a>
            <a class='btn btn-primary float-right' href='/'>Continue shopping</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endif %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>

    </div>
  </main>

{% endblock content %}
```

Following is the error message:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/onlineshopping/add-to-cart/p1/

Django Version: 3.2
Python Version: 3.9.1
Installed Applications:
['django_social_share',
 'django_pgviews',
 'demo',
 'product',
 'signup',
 'signin',
 'home',
 'bmedia',
 'affiliation',
 'pyshorteners',
 'onlineshopping',
 'celery',
 'django_tables2',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\blink\myblink\onlineshopping\views.py", line 124, in add_to_cart
    order_item = OrderItems.objects.get(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 431, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 522, in as_sql
    where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 439, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py", line 81, in as_sql
    sql, params = compiler.compile(child)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 439, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line 132, in as_sql
    return super().as_sql(compiler, connection)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 315, in as_sql
    return super().as_sql(compiler, connection)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 194, in as_sql
    rhs_sql, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 297, in process_rhs
    raise ValueError(

Exception Type: ValueError at /onlineshopping/add-to-cart/p1/
Exception Value: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.
```

Comment: Can you add the error message in the question?

Comment: @allexiusw I have added the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of this snippet:

> ```
>     item = AffProduct.objects.filter(slug=slug)
>     order_item = OrderItem.objects.get(
>         item=item,
>         user=request.user,
>         ordered=False
>     )
> ```

You are filtering by `OrderItem`'s `item` field with an `AffProduct` queryset. You can only use one instance though, hence the error.

If `slug` is unique,  use `get` instead:

```
item = AffProduct.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

If it's not unique, add a way to figure out which one of `AffProduct`s with the same slug will be used as `item`.

Comment: slugs are unique in the database named p1, p2, p3.. and so on. 
I tried using this logic. It says Multiple Objects Returned, Hence, get() returned more than one AffProduct -- it returned 11!

Comment: That actually means it is not unique. In that case, you need to add a way to figure out which of the `AffProduct`s with the same slug will be used.

Comment: Actually, when i created a slug field to the `AffProduct`, all the slugs were named as p1, I rename it with p1, p2 and so on

Comment: I have added the error message, Please help me out

Comment: `Multiple Objects Returned, Hence, get() returned more than one AffProduct -- it returned 11!` -- What was the slug you passed? That slug returned 11 `AffProduct`s

Comment: when i tried added to database the default value for slug as the products were saved before, so I added default value as `p1`

Comment: You need to clean that, or to prevent yourself from doing this again, define `slug` with `unique=True` in your `AffProduct` model

Answer (score 0):

As @bdbd mentioned in his answer you are using the `get()` method which require to filter just one item **No more, no less** in whatever case that you got more or less than one it will run the following errors:

- if less than one object you will get the error `AffProduct.DoesNotExist`
- if more than one object you will get the error `AffProduct.MultipleObjectsReturned`

So to avoid that you have to make sure that the object is unique and the object exists, in that case you always will get one object.

But if you don't have unique data as in your case you have to change to the following:

```
order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(
    item=item,
    user=request.user,
    ordered=False
)
for i in order_item:
    print(i)
else:
    print("No orders in here")
```

But if you want jus one order even though it will lead you to errors you can do this:

```py
order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(
    item=item,
    user=request.user,
    ordered=False
)
order = order_item.first()
if order is not None:
   print(order)
else:
   print('There are not orders in here')
```

Comment: I m getting programming error at administration table, saying `relation "onlineshopping_orderitem" does not exist`, ther is no change or any migrations being applied when i run `migrate`. In Django admin , I can see the table but , when i try to open is says, `Programmin Error`, while in POSTGRESQL, there is no such table being created.

Comment: That's not related to your question. Consider to open a new question for that.